# DNS Server or Modem

Tags: macos, networking, firefox, google-chrome, dns

Last night I started receiving phishing pop ups on my windows machine when using google telling me I needed to upgrade my flash player. After a few hours of virus scans with no results I opened an android tablet to find the same problem when using google. The same problem on all browsers on a mac.

I then pinged google and got 50.31.152.253 which doesn't seem related to google. I then changed the DNS servers to OpenDNS and the problems went. I phoned the ISP and explained what had happened.

They suggested I had a virus or my modem was faulty as they had no DNS problems. Should I explore options such as a corrupted modem and if so how would I go about it.

Comment: Unless your DNS server has been changed its likely your modem.  First step have your provider reset the firmware.  This a gateway/modem or a router?  There is a known issue with hundreds of routers that have a serious exploit if left unpatch is the reason I ask.  Without knowing what your DNS settings were its not possible to tell what really happen

Comment: All machines ( Mac, Android and Windows ) were set to use my ISP's DNS server. As soon as I changed them to OpenDNS the pop ups disappeared.

Comment: Sounds like your ISP servers ads to its customers.  Have you verified the DNS settings were actually to your ISP and not mallicious?  I just know from experience that people think one thing, but reality is something else, and there is no reason to doubt reality until something like this happens

Comment: Thats what I thought but I don't think I'm going to have much chance of them admitting it !

Comment: If you are on a major US ISP it wasn't their DNS.  If you have a discount US ISP it might have been there DNS.  Outside of the US I can't say for certain.

Comment: This news story has something related - http://www.computerworld.in/news/attack-campaign-compromises-300,000-home-routers,-alters-dns-settings

Answer (score 0):

The reverse DNS for that IP has a suspect domain name: studliestman.com and looks like an attempt to infect user's machines (a fake Adobe page with a recommendation to click on a link to run "setup.exe").  Recommend taking a look at your machine's /etc/resolv.conf and the WAN-side DNS your router is using.

It may not be your router that's infected, it could be one of the machines in your home network.  Try turning everything off except the modem and then turning on your tablet.  If the problem doesn't exist anymore, it's not your router.